# Creating shortcuts to source code files with VS

Tags: visual-studio

I know about bookmarks, but what I am really after is the ability to have bookmarks to source files within or outside the project, is there such a thing as bookmarks folder in VS.

PS : This is for reference purpose only and not to include a file in the project as a linked file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [Favorite Documents](https://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension to create menu links to files within or outside the project.